# Creating CSS circle steps connected with lines from top to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I already figure out to do the circle steps horizontally. But to do like the picture below is quite stressful. Can you figure out how to do this?

[image: Image with connected circles]

Here is code

```css
.container-progress {
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.progressbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 16%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: .5em;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: white;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.progressbar li.active+li:after {
  /*background-color: dodgerblue;*/
}

.progressbar label {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-progress">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active active-step">
      <label>step 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 5</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 6</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1dk1frwz/)

Comment: As your tags are `html` and `css` you should probably share your current working example of these to support your question and get more direct help. Preferably a code snippet.

Comment: Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1dk1frwz/

Answer (score 1):

This uses a border on the `ul` to create your connecting lines and uses `position:absolute` to position the individual steps. You will probably need to tweak it a bit more but it could get you moving in the right direction.

**Edit**

To get the first three label to appear above ther cirlces, swap `:before` with `:after`. I've updated my code to reflect this.

```css
.container-progress {
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.progressbar {
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: step;
  position:relative;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  border-left:none;
  min-height:200px;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 16%;
  /*float: left;*/
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*First Three*/
.progressbar li:nth-child(-n+3)
{
  top:-45px
}


/*Last Three*/
.progressbar li:nth-last-child(-n+3)
{
  bottom:-75px
}

/*Left*/
.progressbar li:nth-child(1), .progressbar li:nth-child(6)
{
  left:-45px
}

/*Middle*/
.progressbar li:nth-child(2), .progressbar li:nth-child(5)
{
  left:calc(50% - 45px);
}

/*Right*/
.progressbar li:nth-child(3),  .progressbar li:nth-child(4)
{
  left:calc(100% - 45px);
}

.progressbar li:nth-last-child(-n+3):before, .progressbar li:nth-child(-n+3):after {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 90px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*.progressbar li:after {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: .5em;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}*/

/*.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}*/

.progressbar li.active {
  color: white;
}

.progressbar li.active:before, .progressbar li.active:after {
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.progressbar li.active+li:after {
  /*background-color: dodgerblue;*/
}

.progressbar label {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-progress">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active active-step">
      <label>step 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 5</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>step 6</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice work I deleted my answer as this seems to work great. I was just playing around with things and got busy with other things. I am glad you could get something finished :)

Comment: Nice code. I also got this kind of workaround but with different code. Only the annoying part is the label step 1, 2 and 3 should be above the circles. How to do that? Thank you very much..